# HashMap returning null for String but value for Integer

Tags: java, hashmap

While working with HashMaps ,I find one strange behaviour,

```
   import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] ar) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> ht = new HashMap<>();
            ht.put("1", new Integer(1));
            ht.put("2", new Integer(2));
            ht.put("3", new Integer(3));
            System.out.println(ht.get(2));
        }
    }
```

The above code outputs null.
But if I take key as Integer 1 instead of string ,then value is retrieved .
Can anyone explain the reason for that ,why Integer value is retrieved and not String value.

Comment: It is because your keys are Strings and not Integer. String `"1"` != Integer `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `"2"` is not the same as `Integer(2)`.

A `String` can only be `equals()` to another `String`.
See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) of `String.equals()`:

> The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and **is a `String` object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

An `Integer` can only be `equals()` to another `Integer`.
See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) of `Integer.equals()`:

> The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and **is an `Integer` object** that contains the same `int` value as this object.

So, since `"2"` and `2` are not equal to each other, they are by definition not the same key in a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(ht.get(2))`

to

`System.out.println(ht.get("2"))`

Because key is `String` Type and you passing `Int` Type.